# .htaccess with question mark redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to use .htaccess to rewrite url to my webite:

if url is `https://test.example.com/var1?m=var2`, correct redirection url will be: `https://test.example.com/getid.php?first=var1&second=var2`

an alternative could be:

```
https://test.example.com/getid.php?total=var1?m=var2
```

so, after i will do the split..

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you're probably being tripped up is that the pattern in `RewriteRule` only matches the path part, not the query string -- you need to use `RewriteCond` for that

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} m=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ getid.php?first=$1&second=%1 [L]
```

(the above assumes that `m` is the only query string parameter and will not match if `m` is not present)

Comment: it works, thanks. And how can i add a rule which works even if m is not present? Something like this now doesn't work: https://test.example.com/var1

Comment: Add a question mark after the `m=(.*)` to make it optional: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (m=(.*))?` (now that there are 2 regex capture groups you'll also need to change the %1 to a %2 since you want the second, inner group)

Answer (score 0):

You need a .htaccess on you server webroot path with this in in it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ getid.php?total=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Basiclly. 
Thing you should read into the topic: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html

Comment: mmm no! this not work: https://test.example.com/var1?m=var2 redirect to https://test.example.com/getid.php?total=var1